# Are these statements the same if (x - y) {} vs. if (x !=y) {}

Tags: c++, c

I have been programming for a while, and it seems to me the following two if statements would produce identical result, but I always question it, can someone help me to resuve this question?

```
int x, y;
if (x - y) {
  //some code
}
```

vs

```
int x, y;
if (x != y) (
  // some code
}
```

Thanks...

Comment: Certainly depends on the type of `x` and `y`.

Comment: Well, only if other values than zero mean true. Also on the type of `x` and `y` since the expression `x-y` must evaluate to number...

Comment: @tomi `operator-` can return an arbitrary type, including a `bool`.

Comment: Correctness aside, in my opinion the first variant obfuscates the meaning of the statement. Also, even when they are both correct, my guess would be that the second one would tend to be more efficient, though that would of course depend on what exact compiler was used.

Comment: Usage of uninitialized variable is undefined behaviour, so... they may or may not be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not if `(x-y)` can cause an overflow. In the event of overflow the behavior is undefined. On some systems it may wrap, on others it may set the result to 0 (which will give you false positives).

Comment: How can a system *"incorrectly"* implement undefined behavior?

Comment: @IInspectable Sorry, I meant that setting to 0 would cause incorrect behavior. Fixed now.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the type of `x` and `y`.

Assuming `x` and `y` are both `int`, the two statements are not equivalent as `x - y` would invoke undefined behavior if the result is not representable in an `int`.

Assuming `x` and `y` are both `unsigned int`, the two statements are equivalent (`unsigned int` do no overflow).

Comment: Unsigned int can certainly overflow. It's just that the behavior in such situations is defined.

Comment: @RobKennedy well I'm using the C Standard terminology here: *A computation involving unsigned operands can never overflow [...]* (C99, 6.2.5p9).

Comment: If they're pointers, `x - y` has undefined behavior unless `x` and `y` both point into the same object (or just past the end of it). If they're floating-point, overflow is certainly an issue, and loss of precision might be. If there's a user-defined `operator-` (C++ only), it depends on how it's defined. If they're of distinct types but convertible to a common type for the `-` or `!=` operator, or if one is a pointer expression and the other is a null pointer constant -- pardon me, my head is starting to hurt.

Comment: @KeithThompson: In IEEE 754, `x-y` is zero if and only if `x == y`, unless `x` and `y` are the same-sign infinity. There is no overflow, precision, or rounding issue, except the former may signal conditions the latter does not, except when `x` and `y` are the same-sign infinity.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: `x - y` can overflow (causing undefined behavior) if, for example, `x == DBL_MIN` and `y == -DBL_MIN`. I suppose IEEE requires the result to be `Infinity` (depending on flags?), but neither C nor C++ requires IEEE.

Comment: @KeithThompson: My statement is correct: It predicates IEEE 754.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Your statement is correct as stated, but it doesn't apply to non-IEEE implementations.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Yes, my statement is not about things it is not about. I apologize for the fact that my statement is not about everything. I believed there was value in comprehending the most widely used floating-point system.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: It wasn't sufficiently clear to me that the introductory phrase "In IEEE" applied to your entire comment. I should have just said that. It's now clear to me that that was your intent.